# IIS custom SMTP module

Tags: c#, iis, smtp

when configuring SMTP server in IIS, is there a way to intercept all incoming SMTP messages in a IIS C# module, and possibly change the SMTP message before forwarding it (similar to creating custom HTTP module by inheriting from IHttpModule)?

Comment: SMTP is no longer part of IIS starting from IIS 7, so a C# IIS module won't work as you wished.

Answer (score 0):

To monitor all incoming messages, you should write a windows service or an exe which can be scheduled to run once in every few seconds. The service can run on any windows server (with required softwares installed). To read more about how to check incoming emails, check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614837/how-do-i-read-incoming-mail-using-c-sharp).